# angularJs - unit testing using jasmine. How to delete a spy ? Getting Error: <spyOn> : getList has already been spied upon

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test case for a particular angular service method which is being used in my controller.

My ***getListCtrlSpec.js*** file is below,

```
    /**
 * Spec Suite for "getListCtrl" controller
 */

describe('Controller : getListCtrl', function () {
    /* Load the reuqired module */
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    /*Initialize the variables */
    var getListCtrl,
        scope,
        $rootScope,
        someService
// Provide will help us create fake implementations for our dependencies
beforeEach(function () {
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.service('someService', function () {

        });

    });
});
/* Initilaize the controller and mock a scope */
beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_,_someService_,) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller = _$controller_;


    getListCtrl = $controller('getListCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        someService: _someService_
    });

someService.getList = jasmine.createSpy('getList').and.returnValue([{}]);
}));

/* Spec To check if the controller is instantaiated */
it('should get an instance of getListCtrl - ', function () {
    expect(getListCtrl).toBeDefined();
});

it('should check for successCb function for getList method for Asia - ', function () {
    spyOn(someService, 'getList').and.returnValue(listForAsianCountries);
    var data = listForAsianCountries;
    scope.getListSuccessCb(data);
});

 it('should check for successCb function for getList method for Europe - ', function () {
    spyOn(someService, 'getList').and.returnValue(listForEuropeanCountries);
    var data = listForEuropeanCountries;
    scope.getListSuccessCb(data);
});
});
```

I am getting an error

```
Error: <spyOn> : getList has already been spied upon
```

How do i delete a spy? I need to still test the same successCb function for atleast 10 more conditions like those mentioned in the "it" block.

Answer (score -3):

`yourCoolService.createThing = jasmine.createSpy('notreal', function(){}).and.returnValue();`

your jasmine test will run but when you go to fire up your app typescript will yell loudly at you if you don't put a random string and an empty function as the args to `createSpy()`.

peace

Comment: sorry , but i was wanting to get some more insights on modifying/Deleting a spy. My jasmine tests are running fine. Also i am not working on typescript currently.